# How do I test a video chat with a second computer without https?

Tags: http, video, https, webrtc, getusermedia

I have created a video chat app with React, express, peerjs. However, when I connect to my localhost with a second computer via the IP address I connect nicely but the video will not appear. The console says it doesn't recognise getUserMedia(). My research says browsers require a https rather than http for security when using getUserMedia(). Is there anyway around this issue as setting up https seems difficult without an up and running website? I merely want to check if the video works with the camera on a second computer.

Comment: This is a notorious pain in the xxx. I do it by deploying my web server code to glitch.com. [My note on the topic](https://www.plumislandmedia.net/programming/javascript/testing-https-getusermedia-webrtc/).

Answer (score 2):

You can test it with chromium if you start it with a flag:

`--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="http://youraddress"`

It will bypass the restriction to access getUserMedia(). But it will only work in chromium-based browsers.

If you need to test the others as well, another way would be to run `nginx` locally and `proxy_pass` requests on localhost to your other machine. Browser will think the website is on localhost and will allow using `getUserMedia` .
Here's a nginx config example to do that:

```
server {
    listen <port>;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://<server_host>:<port>;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

And then run it with: `nginx -c <config_location>`.

Comment: Thank you for your time. This has disabled the getUserMedia() error. I'm not getting the local video in the remote computer nor is the local computer getting the remote video but that wasn't my original question. Your answer solved the current issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A very useful service to do this locally on your machine is [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). I use it all the time for quick WebRTC tests.

Answer (score 0):

Add a self signed certificat to your test webserver , it doesn't matter in test environment.
You manually trust it in the browser and getUserMedia work.